# Getting seconds between two Oracle Timestamps

Tags: oracle, timestamp

Tom Kyte [suggests](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:10729709873260) to use [`EXTRACT`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm) to get the difference:

```
extract( day from (x-y) )*24*60*60+
extract( hour from (x-y) )*60*60+
...
```

This seems to be harder to read and slower than this, for example:

```
( CAST( x AS DATE ) - CAST( y AS DATE ) ) * 86400
```

---

So, what is the way to get the difference between two Timestamps in seconds? Thanks!

Comment: Personally I prefer 24*60*60 to 86400. Even a non-techie would recognize 24 as hours in a day and work out that the 60s related to minutes and seconds.

Comment: @Gary: That's definitely true, thanks!

Comment: Please note that the results are not identical (see my comment below)

Comment: The method with the cast might produce wrong results because of "daylight saving" in different time zones. The extract handles this correctly.

Answer (score 18):

**"Best Practice"**

Whatever you do, wrap it in a function, e.g. `seconds_between (from_date, to_date)` - doesn't matter how it does it (choose the most efficient method) - then it will be perfectly obvious what your code is doing.

**Performance**

I tested the two methods on 11gR1 on my laptop (WinXP) with the test case below. It seems the CAST option is the fastest. (t1 is baseline, t2 used the `extract` method, t3 used the `cast` method)

```
t1 (nothing) 3
t2 (extract) 338
t3 (cast)    101

t1 (nothing) 3
t2 (extract) 336
t3 (cast)    100
```

**Test script**

```
declare
 x TIMESTAMP := SYSTIMESTAMP;
 y TIMESTAMP := TRUNC(SYSDATE);
 n PLS_INTEGER;
 lc CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER := 1000000;
 t1 PLS_INTEGER;
 t2 PLS_INTEGER;
 t3 PLS_INTEGER;
begin
 t1 := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;
 for i in 1..lc loop
  n := i;
 end loop;
 t1 := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time - t1;
 t2 := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;
 for i in 1..lc loop
  n := extract(day from (x-y))*24*60*60
     + extract(hour from (x-y))*60*60
     + extract(minute from (x-y))*60
     + extract(second from (x-y));
 end loop;
 t2 := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time - t2;
 t3 := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;
 for i in 1..lc loop
  n := ( CAST( x AS DATE ) - CAST( y AS DATE ) ) * 86400;
 end loop;
 t3 := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time - t3;
 dbms_output.put_line('t1 (nothing) ' || t1);
 dbms_output.put_line('t2 (extract) ' || t2);
 dbms_output.put_line('t3 (cast)    ' || t3);
end;
```

Comment: While this is an important point (`+1`), I am actually searching for that most efficient method that you talk about :)

Comment: There might not be that much difference - test it (e.g. run each a few thousand times with various inputs) and see.

Comment: @Peter: there you go :) hope it helps

Comment: Just noted that the `extract` method includes fractions of a second, whereas the `cast` method truncates them.

Comment: @Jeffrey: Thanks, I had already tested those two attempts (my question says that the first one is slower). Still curious, if there are other ways, or if there is a "right way" to do it :)

Comment: Well, I'd say the "right way" would probably be `(x-y)`, which yields an interval. Then, it's just a matter of how you want the interval represented or displayed (e.g. extract out the relevant parts to convert to a number of seconds).

Comment: `"Whatever you do, wrap it in a function, e.g. seconds_between (from_date, to_date) - doesn't matter how it does it (choose the most efficient method) - then it will be perfectly obvious what your code is doing." `  -- this is wise advice. +1

Answer (score 13):

**Alternative:**
I found this to work as well to get the difference in seconds including milliseconds.
It's even save for time-zones with "daylight saving" while the extract method would have a problem.
Unfortunately the difference between t1 and t2 is limited for the result to be right. Casting timestamps to date format is not an option because the fractions of seconds are lost.

```
select (sysdate + (t2 - t1)*1000 - sysdate) * 86.4 from 
(select  
    to_timestamp('2014-03-30 01:00:10.111','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') at time zone 'MET' t1, 
    to_timestamp('2014-03-30 03:00:10.112','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') at time zone 'MET' t2 
 from dual);
```

Comment: This is a great trick! Wrap that in a round(), and you're all set.

Answer (score 6):

for fast and easy use:

```
extract( day from(t2 - t1)*24*60*60)
```

**Example:**

```
with dates as (
   select
        to_timestamp('2019-06-18 22:50:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') t1
      , to_timestamp('2019-06-19 00:00:38', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') t2
   from dual
)
select
    extract( day from(t2 - t1)*24*60*60) diff_in_seconds
from dates
;
```

**Output:**

```
DIFF_IN_SECONDS
---------------
            638
```

Answer (score 3):

I have always used the second way i.e. compare the DATEs (which gives you the number of days difference, with a fractional part), and the multiply by the factor you want to give you number of hours, minutes, seconds, or whatever.

I think it's good, and easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I find:

```
extract(day from (x-y))*24*60*60 + ... + extract(second from (x-y))
```

clearer in purpose than...

```
( CAST( x AS DATE ) - CAST( y AS DATE ) ) * 86400
```

to get the difference in seconds.

Tom's method takes a few more keystrokes but the intent is clear.

Answer (score -3):

```
to_number(to_char(t2, 'yyyymmddhh24missff')) - to_number(to_char(t1, 'yyyymmddhh24missff'))
```

Comment: This will result in a difference of 41 seconds between `00:00:59` and `00:01:00`.