# how to perform this step in sql query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am currently doing this excel via VBA, but if I can get some help to do it with in query would be really save me lots of time.

This is 1 of like 5 things I need to do for this report I am working on.

**Tables**
I am reading from 3 different tables

```
TableA   TableB  TableC
```

Fields from **tableA**

```
OUT_ID
```

Fields from **tableB**

```
timestamp
event_type
worker
operator_id
new_date
```

Fields from **tableC**

```
worker
```

**Query**

```
Select
       TableA.OUT_ID,
       TableB.timestamp,
       TableB.new_date,
       TableB.event_type,
       TableC.worker,
       TableB.operator_id

From TableA left outer join
        TableB 
           ON TableA.OUT_ID = TableB.OUT_ID and
                 TableB.event_type in ('WORKER_RET_CMT_CHANCE','RET_CHANCE','WORKER_STATUS_CHANCE') Left OUTER JOIN 
              TableC 
                ON TableB.worker = TableC.worker
 where  TableA.time_stamp > {?PickDate} //parameter in crystal report to pick date
    and TableA.time_stamp < {?RestDate}  //parameter in crystal report to pick date 
   order by TableA.OUT_ID, TableB.timestamp
```

**Here is what I need to do.**

In `Event_type` column if `RET_CHANCE` has `WORKER_RET_COMMENT_CHANCE` in next row then check if `OUT_ID` is same, if it is same than check if `TIMESTAMP` difference is less than 10 seconds, if all this is true than copy `WORKER` number from yellow cell to red cell.

Please see image blow and attached excel file for sample.
[Download excel file via dropbox](http://db.tt/AGx5m6pO)

[image]

Comment: I'll put it up for bounty or Paypal hire but I need more than just 1 step. if anyone interested please contact me via email

Comment: You'd best formally define what order these records are in, because "next row" is meaningless without it.

Comment: @DavidAldridge rarely `WORKER_ERT_COMMENT_CHANCE` will be on the top row and `RET_CHANCE` will be on next row if that is case than I need to perform same steps.back to your question it is order by `TableA.OUT_ID`, `TableA.timestamp`

Comment: That's not sufficient to define why RET_CHANCE is "before" WORKER_RET_COMMENT_CHANCE though.

Comment: Are you saying that "next row" means something other than the next row according to the `ORDER BY` clause that you specified in the query?  Or can we just look at the next row ordered by `timestamp` for the particular `out_id`?

Comment: If *green* records for `OUT_ID` = **2135** were in reverse order (due to a difference in milliseconds), would you still look at this very pair?

Comment: @DavidAldridge I really don't have the architecture of the design. so I can't tell you why 99% of times `RET_CHANCE` comes before `WORKER_RET_COMMENT_CHANCE`, but you can see the timestamp in 2nd column in PIC that they occurred at the same time.

Comment: @JustinCave by next row meaning I meant that this whole data is based on TIMESTAMP for example when `OUT_ID` = `2135` @ 8:35:20 AM `RET_CHANCE` happened(or came into DB) then at @ 8:36:55 AM `WORKER_SATUS_CHANCE` and so on. so if when Event_type=`RET_CHANCE` and if next row or thing happened is `WORKER_RET_COMMENT_CHANCE` and check if timestamp difference between those 2 is less than 10 seconds and both of they out_id is same then copy whatever is in yellow to red.

Comment: @PM77-1 , if I understood your question correctly, when `OUT_ID` = **2135** for both green records one was 8:43:10 AM and other was 8:43:15 AM than I would still like to consider this pair and copy yellow cell to red cell. or if you meant if `ORKER_RET_COMMENT_CHANCE` was in top row and `RET_CHANCE` was on bottom then also consider this situation.

Comment: @Mowgli - Please see the code I posted in my *non-answer* and comment on it.  Does such grouping satisfy your requirements?

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** a complete answer but just an attempt to clarify the task.  It requires some code that will not be very readable in comments.  So (everybody) please bear with me.

Will the following `SELF JOIN` create the **correct pairing** of the records:

```
FROM View1 v1
JOIN View1 v2 ON v1.out_id = v2.out_id AND 
                 v1.event_type = 'RET_CHANCE' AND v2.event_type = 'WORKER_RET_COMMENT_CHANCE' AND              
                 ABS(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM v1.timestamp) - EXTRACT(SECOND FROM v2.timestamp)) < 10
```

Comment: Thanks, I never used view, but looking just at condition it looks to me.

Comment: I just named your resulting dataset as `View1` so I did not have to include your entire query into my answer.

Comment: *ABS(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM v1.timestamp) - EXTRACT(SECOND FROM v2.timestamp)) < 10* isn't correct. That subtracts the second component of the timestamps.

Comment: I guess there's no substitution for `Ask Tom`'s solution: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551242712657900129

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that you have a "next row" requirement it seemss like a good time to use the [LEAD](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions074.htm) function.

As the documentation states

> LEAD is an analytic function. It provides access to more than one row
>   of a table at the same time without a self join. Given a series of
>   rows returned from a query and a position of the cursor, LEAD provides
>   access to a row at a given physical offset beyond that position

So in order to get the "next event", "next timestamp" and "next worker" we need do do

```
LEAD(timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY ???) next_timestamp, 
LEAD(EVENT_TYPE) OVER (ORDER BY ???) next_event,
LEAD(WORKER) OVER (ORDER BY ??) NEXT_WORKER
```

The ORDER BY Clause here tells us what the "next row" is. 
Since you had

```
order by TableA.OUT_ID, TableB.timestamp
```

We could do

```
... OVER (ORDER BY OUT_ID, timestamp)
```

that but you also had the requirement "check if OUT_ID is the same". We can add the optional PARTITION BY clause which will ensure that the "next record" is used for the same OUT_ID

... OVER (PARTITION BY OUT_ID ORDER BY timestamp)

Once we have all the "Next Fields" we can you use a CASE statement to fullfill the remaining requirements

- If the Event_type is RET_CHANCE
- And the Event Type in the next row is WORKER_RET_COMMENT_CHANCE
- And the TimeStamps from the two row is less then 10 seconds
- Then use the worker from the next row

The following query is a demonstration of these ideas.

```
WITH Data AS (
SELECT 
  OUT_ID,
  timestamp,
  LEAD(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY Out_ID ORDER BY TimeStamp) next_timestamp, 
  Event_type,
  LEAD(EVENT_TYPE) OVER (PARTITION BY Out_ID ORDER BY TimeStamp) next_event,
  WORKER,
  LEAD(WORKER) OVER (PARTITION BY Out_ID ORDER BY TimeStamp) NEXT_WORKER
FROM TableB
ORDER BY 
   OUT_ID,
   timestamp
)
SELECT 

  OUT_ID,
  timestamp,
  next_timestamp, 
  Event_type,
  next_event,
  WORKER,
  NEXT_WORKER,
( CAST( next_timestamp AS DATE ) - CAST( timestamp AS DATE ) ) * 86400 DIFF,
  CASE WHEN 
        EVENT_TYPE ='RET_CHANCE'
        AND next_event = 'WORKER_STATUS_CHANCE'
        AND ( CAST( next_timestamp AS DATE ) - CAST( timestamp AS DATE ) ) * 86400  < 10 
       THEN NEXT_WORKER
       ELSE WORKER
   END as CALC_WORKER
FROM 
  data
```

Notes:

- You don't need to use the with clause here but it would make the `CASE` statement unreadable.
- I left in all the NEXT_* fields so that you can see how the query works.
- Using Jeffrey Kemp's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3964369/119477) for calculating the seconds difference

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/764a6/33)

Comment: In Oracle subtraction of DATE type fields yields the result in **days**.  Aren't you loosing the time component with your logic?

Comment: @PM77-1 I guess the proof is in the pudding. It didn't in the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/764a6/33) See the Diff column. When I attempted to use your [Extract method it didn't work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/764a6/29). Also note that the asktom article uses the date datatype

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I've updated my answer to include a description of solution. Is there something in particular that I'm not explaining well?