# How to find the total time the machine is idle on the primary key, knowing the start date and end date?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

How to find the total time the machine is idle on the primary key, knowing the start date and end date ?

It's rows result

```
DEVICE_ID FIRST_DATE              SECOND_DATE              DURATION
237017,  "2014-04-21 18:34:19.0", "2014-04-21 18:27:28.0", "0 Clock 6 Min 51 Sec "
237017,  "2014-04-21 18:51:36.0", "2014-04-21 18:34:19.0", "0 Clock 17 Min 16 Sec "
237017,  "2014-04-21 18:53:52.0", "2014-04-21 18:51:36.0", "0 Clock 2 Min 16 Sec "
237017,  "2014-04-22 12:20:16.0", "2014-04-21 18:53:52.0", "17 Clock 26 Min 24 Sec "
237017,  "2014-04-22 14:41:28.0", "2014-04-22 12:20:16.0", "2 Clock 21 Min 12 Sec "
237031,  "2014-04-08 16:20:12.0", "2014-04-08 16:19:11.0", "0 Clock 1 Min 1 Sec "
```

Comment: How do you define idle?

Comment: Are you storing dates (timestamps) and durations as strings? What constitutes idle - those ranges, or anything outside those ranges; if the latter will your start/end date be outside any ranges? And what do you have so far?

Comment: How do I know the duration format UNIX? Date Format timestamp

Comment: i don't save duration, it's select query

Comment: Consider creating sqlfiddle

Comment: how find duration timestamp in format unix ? SECOND_DATE - FIRST_DATE

Comment: Can a device be idle before the earliest start date or after the latest end date? Or earliest start date and latest end date is the device total working range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  id, TO_TIMESTAMP (SECOND_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') - TO_TIMESTAMP (FIRST_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') tdiff from t;
```

This will give you the difference in timestamp format. You can use the EXTRACT method then to convert this into days/hours/mins etc as in the link below:

[Getting seconds between two Oracle Timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957909/getting-seconds-between-two-oracle-timestamps)